# Identifying question type (Natural Language)

Tags: natural-language

So far, I found an article about this: [Question answering System](http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJDTA/vol4_no2/9.pdf)

As it can be seen on page 105 (section 3.1) and the graph in section 3.2, the questions can be classified depending on which words come after each why/what/where.

Is there any model that you know about that is complete for describing questions? (i.e. how *long* is for length, how *old* is for age, etc)

I tried searching for English Language Model Ontology but so far I didn't get too far. My problem is, probably, that I don't know the name of the term I'm trying to find.

Comment: I usually use [discourse representation theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_representation_theory) to solve this problem.  For example, "How old is X?" or "How young is X?" or "What is X's age?" can all be rewritten as "What is the age of X?"